# OSError appears when trying to run an application on flet

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, flet

I'm trying to run my application using the flet (GUI) library, but the following error appears:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1 (\__connection_loop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Lib\\threading.py", line 1073, in \_bootstrap_inner

> > >     self.run()

File "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Lib\\threading.py", line 1010, in run
self.\_target(\*self.\_args, \*\*self.\_kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\somokill\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python312\\site-packages\\flet_runtime\\sync_local_socket_connection.py", line 150, in \__connection_loop
self.\__connection, client_address = self.\__sock.accept()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Lib\\socket.py", line 295, in accept
fd, addr = self.\_accept()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: \[WinError 10038\] An attempt was made to perform an operation on an object that is not a socket
```

Here's my code:

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = 'Main App'
    page.theme_mode = 'dark'
    page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(text='Button'))


ft.app(target=main)
```

I'm currently running Windows 10 LTSC 2021, but when I was running Linux Fedora Xfce everything worked fine.

I don't know how to fix this error. I will be glad for any help.